# How to convert "23.99999999999999" (repeating decimal with a repetend of 9) to "24" (correct integer) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When I execute the JavaScript code `8/(3-8/3)`, the result is displayed as `23.99999999999999`, but I want to fix it to `24`.

In order not to round numbers when they are not repeating decimals or when their repetend is not 9 (e.g. do not round `21.835` to `22`; do not round `2.979797979797` to `3`), how should I solve this problem?

Comment: The result isn't "displayed as" 23.99999999999999, it _is_ 23.99999999999999, because you're using decimal fractions with IEEE floating point numbers. Which are binary, not decimal. There are numbers that IEEE floats _cannot_ represent, so you're seeing the nearest value that an IEEE floating point number _can_ represent. The best fix is to rearrange your math.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a clear way to resolve this issue without using some sort of rounding function, but there are alternative ways to write this specific equation, according to [MathsIsFun](https://www.mathsisfun.com/puzzles/24-from-8-8-3-3-solution.html)

E.g.

`8/(1/3)`